# Object moved to here in response of Jmeter request

Tags: jmeter, httpwebresponse, sessionid, response.redirect, httpcookie

I am new Jmeter, I have recorded a JMeter script. When I am playing login request for my website in response I am getting "Object Moved to here" instead of getting expected result.

I have created Cookie Manager & Cache Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Object Moved to here -302 error code - it just means you are being redirected. 
Check your property: Follow redirects in HTTP Request. It should be turned on.